# Issue with setInterval function call

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm trying to call the setInterval function in my pop up window to update the time every second but when it is called my HTML page doesn't update at all just shows the initial time upon loading.  I can't see what I'm doing wrong with this code.

```
    var currentTime = new Date();

window.self.setInterval(
    function()
    { 
        window.self.document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML = currentTime.toTimeString();
    }, 1000 );
```

Any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`currentTime` is being set once and only once. You need to create a new Date object at every interval. Something like this:

```
setInterval(
  function()
  { 
    document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML = (new Date()).toTimeString();
  },
  1000
);
```

Comment: Yes, this worked.  I didn't realize that I needed a new Date object every single time it was called.  So it was literally just calling the same Date object with the same time string over and over.  So it was working just not the way I wanted it to.  Thanks, can't believe something that simple went over my head.